# copy constructor accessing fields of its class?

Tags: java, copy-constructor

I was reading about mutable/immutable classes and copy constructors in java and stumbled across [this example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12).

Inside the copy constructor he uses the getters as below:

```
 /**
  * Copy constructor.
  */
  public Galaxy(Galaxy aGalaxy) {
    this(aGalaxy.getMass(), aGalaxy.getName());
    //no defensive copies are created here, since 
    //there are no mutable object fields (String is immutable)
  }
```

My question is, are there any other reasons than being it's a good coding practice, for someone to use getters inside the copy constructor rather than just accessing the fields like: `(aGalaxy.aMass, aGalaxy.aName)`. You can find examples that does that as well but i mean is it purely a coding style or are there potential benefits of using getters inside the copy constructor?

Comment: A 'degraded copy' of a derived Galaxy class, which for example dynamically computes its name from mass, sky area, time of discovery, etc and *doesn't use the `Galaxy.name` to store the results of the computation*. As you cannot control what others will do with your class, not trusting them is a good defensive tactic (which you may pay with extra CPU time)

Comment: Did you mean the use of aGalaxy.aMass is a better way? I would think the same as using getters could lead to inconsistencies here.

Comment: On the contrary, using the getters is safer.

Comment: yes but not in this case right?

Comment: imho, in most case (for copy ctor), it should be preferrable to access field directly because it is within the same class, and the class itself should have knowledge on its internal representation and know how to perform a proper copy (at least under its own context).  Accessing through getters are actually creating confusion (and problem as mentioned in other answer)

Comment: And, in most cases, you shouldn't even have getters for your internal fields.  Getters are Evil.  You should have your class provide meaningful behavior, instead of exposing its internal implementation detail (through getters, or even worse, public fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although innocuous in most situations, this practice can lead to some hard-to-catch bugs when subclasses choose to override the getters that you call.

Here is a simple example:

```
class Base {
    private final String name;
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public Base(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Base(Base b) {
        this(b.getName());
    }
}
class Derived extends Base {
    public String getName() {
        return "["+super.getName()+"]";
    }
    public Derived(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    public Derived(Derived d) {
        this(d.getName());
    }
}
```

Note how `Derived` overrides `getName()`, and so the copy constructor of `Derived` is accessing a modified version of the name, leading to a problem:

```
Derived orig = new Derived("hello");
Derived copy = new Derived(orig);
System.out.println(orig.getName()); // Prints [hello]
System.out.println(copy.getName()); // Prints [[hello]]
```

The last print has square brackets doubled, so the copy is not really a copy.

Using `protected` variables or making your getters `final` would have helped you to avoid this problem.

I think the root cause of this problem is letting subclasses override getters for stored properties, so I would prefer the approach of making your getters `final`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/4QaR9s)